# Addition of integrals with different variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I came across to an interesting problem recently, which can be solved if it is assumed that I can add $N$ integrals defined on the same domain, but using different variables, together, under the same integral. Formally; let's assume that we have this expression: $$ \sum_{n=0}^{N}\int_{\Omega}g_n(x_n)dx_n$$.

The functions are well behaving and have valid integrals on the domain $\Omega$. How can I show that this expression can be stated as:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N}\int_{\Omega}g_n(x_n)dx_n = \int_{\Omega}(g_1(y) + g_2(y) + \dots + g_N(y))dy$$

Since each integral here is actually the limit of Riemann Sums using functions $g_n$ on the domain $\Omega$ I think this is valid, but I cannot show it in a proper way. What should be done in this case? How can show that this holds?

Answer (score 2):

Since each integral is on the same domain, doesn't a simple change of variables $y=x_n$ (for each $n$) do the trick?  It does because the change of variables does not change the domain of integration, $\Omega$.